# Drawing above the sublayer of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, drawrect

I have a `UIView`. I have added a sublayer, to the UIView, which looks like a shadow. I am trying to draw inside the UIView. But the added sublayer appears above what I have drawn. I want my drawn content to be above the added sublayer. How do I do this? Thanks.

[This](http://postimg.org/image/4whqhyew5/) is what I am getting.

```
//  adding the sublayer

CAGradientLayer * gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = gradientFrame;
gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.05f] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], nil];
[gradientLayer setTransform:CATransform3DMakeRotation(45.0 / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)];

//  drawing code

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, [self bounds]);
}
```

Comment: you are drawing on the uiview's layer which is ofcourse behind any added sublayers. you can add another layer ontop of sublayer & draw on it instead.

Comment: I solved it by adding another layer and filling it with color so that the gradientlayer isn't visible. I wanted to do it without doing it this way because I was afraid adding many layers might take too much memory. Thanks for the immediate help @nsuinteger.

Comment: welcome & more than memory you will need to take of resizing adjusting frames every-time there is a change (rotation, etc)